# CSS @font-face: how to use it properly?

Tags: css, fonts

I downloaded a new font and stores in in `${RootFolder}/font`.
In **styles.css** file I wrote:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: roboto;
    url('../fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf');
}
h1 {
    font-family: roboto;
}
```

In html I wrote:

```
<h1> hello </h1>
```

And still I don't see that font has changed.

Do you know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "roboto";
   src: url('fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf');
}
h1 {
   font-family: roboto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use google fonts https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto
Just import this into the css. Replace the @font-face with:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700');
```

And use like `font-family: roboto;`

Answer (score 1):

in your font-face add src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'); instead of url('../fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf');

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp